# Asterisk AMI: DTMF not received on SIP channel

Tags: sip, asterisk, dtmf

I'm sending DTMF to Asterisk using python and pyst. The code is:

```
def playDTMF(self, channel, digit):
        print "DTMF: Sending %s to %s" % (digit, channel)
        response = self.manager.send_action({
            "Action" : "PlayDTMF",
            "Channel" : channel,
            "Digit" : digit
        })
        print "DTMF: %s - %s" % (response['Response'], response['Message'])
```

Output of the script is good:

```
DTMF: Sending 1 to SIP/S3bc9c3c-00000081
DTMF: Success - DTMF successfully queued
```

But Asterisk reacts to it like that:

```
[Jul  2 17:48:53] DEBUG[6967] manager.c: Running action 'PlayDTMF'
[Jul  2 17:48:53] DEBUG[6967] channel.c: Set channel SIP/S3bc9c3c-00000081 to write format slin
[Jul  2 17:48:53] DEBUG[6967] channel.c: Scheduling timer at (50 requested / 50 actual) timer ticks per second
[Jul  2 17:48:53] DEBUG[6967] channel.c: Thread 140629726328576 Blocking 'SIP/S3bc9c3c-00000081', already blocked by thread 140628353554176 in procedure ast_
waitfor_nandfds
```

The interesting thing is that this happens only on SIP channel. On "Local" channel it works as expected:

```
[Jul  2 18:00:07] DTMF[7951]: channel.c:4083 __ast_read: DTMF begin '1' received on Local/901@AC000001-19ca;1
[Jul  2 18:00:07] DTMF[7951]: channel.c:4093 __ast_read: DTMF begin passthrough '1' on Local/901@AC000001-19ca;1
```

How can I let DTMF play properly on SIP channel?

**UPD**

Found this on Asterisk bugtracker: https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-13224

Seems that if I send DTMF to SIP channel phone just plays it for himself, and it doesn't go further to Asterisk. Is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: what version of `*` are you using, does the call continues normally after that (ie. if dtmf 1 than foo; else bar)

Comment: It reacts somehow, phone beeps and playback stops. Call continues as usual. Besides, while using rfc2833 there is no beep or any other reaction.

Comment: The bug was closed as not-a-bug, and it's dated closed as June, 2011.  So I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.  I'll try and recreate your problem on my PBX this afternoon and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

use SendDTMF appliction.
SendDTMF(digits[|timeout_ms])

Comment: There is no such action as SendDTMF in Asterisk AMI. I googled that is is available through AGI but I recall there were some problems with AGI which didn't allow me to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your SIP.CONF, ensure you have

```
dtmfmode=rfc2833
```

for your appropriate SIP trunk.  Often sending DTMF inband (audio) with SIP doesn't work as well as you might hope.

Comment: `rfc2833` doesn't work at all. In answer below I commented "while using rfc2833 there is no beep or any other reaction".

Comment: Check out the pcap on that... You might not hear it, but, it may just be in an RTP-like packet. Depending on how your ITSP operates a gateway will determine how the behavior is on the PSTN.

Comment: With `rfc2833` there is no sound in the phone, but Asterisk log is the same.

Comment: By definition, RFC2833 will produce no sound on the line.  It is sending the DTMF as out-of-band command signals.  It depends on the end points to render sound, if they want.