# Asterisk AMI - How to simulate a DTMF sending action over AMI

Tags: asterisk

I am building an application in Asterisk , which has to simulate the phone keypress action i.e DTMF. For instance , if a caller calls a number and the IVR requires to press a digit , the application (say a webpage) should also be able to simulate the same key press. I tried the following:
- I have a web application that triggers PlayDTMF action over AMI to simulate the key press on the caller channel. Unfortunately this didn't work , as it  played the DTMF digit on the channel (the keypress could be heard) but asterisk didn't receive the DTMF. It was just playing the DTMF, which is what the AMI action was designed for. I technically need to "send" the DTMF digit on the channel.
- the sendDTMF function in asterisk couldn't be used either,as it is a dialplan function and I need a AMI action to trigger DTMF from an external source.

A similar issue was reported sometime back: [Asterisk AMI: DTMF not received on SIP channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422777/asterisk-ami-dtmf-not-received-on-sip-channel)

I am using Asterisk 11. Is there a way to implement the above using AMI/AGI? Or do i need to further upgrade my Asterisk to 12 to make use of ARI?

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Asterisk 12 or 13 upgrade will not help you. You not understand how asterisk works at current moment.

Comment: How can i simulate DTMF in Asterisk 11. Additionally I tried to originate a call on a Local channel and use the sendDTMF method to trigger a DTMF action to the channel I want. I do hear the DTMF tone on the desired channel..but like the PlayDTMF AMI action , this too is not captured by Asterisk for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to simulate the DTMF action , by Dialing/Originating out to a local context and using the outgoing bridging channel id for DTMF input. So the flow is :
call lands on Asterisk -> Asterisk Dials out to a Local context -> The dialout creates a bridging event which has the outgoing channel id(store in some DB) -> The local context can have the IVR flow and using the stored channel and PLayDTMF action - dtmf digits can be inserted. Not sure if there is a more elegant solution to this!